# How to make chart for large data set of 5 billion records

Tags: osx, data-visualization, charts

I have a CSV file of more than 5 billion entries in it. I want to create a line or area chart for this data (data row number as x, value as y). Which software I can use to do so?

The file has only one column and all values are floating values with 3 decimal points.
The file size is 34GB.

Sample:

```
23287.323
50982.287
71124.691
[...]
```

Comment: We'll need much more information to provide a solid recommendation. Please, take some time to read through our [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/46) and [edit] your question to match them. What requirements do you have? What would be nice to have, but not required? What operating system should it run on? After you [edit] your question to contain more information, we can reopen it. Thanks!

Comment: Again, as @Undo said: Which OS? Price? Do you have a budget? Are there any additional **requirements?**

Comment: I am on MAC OS X 10.11

Comment: So you just want a (any) program that will do that on your mac? What do you want to do with the chart afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to generate this graph is probably with [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/).

Let's say your data is in a file called `data.csv`. Then put the following script in a file called `graph.gnuplot`:

```
set yrange [0:100000]
set grid
set term png
set output 'graph.png'
plot \
  0.01 with lines lt 1, \
  'data.csv' u 0:1:2 with line lt -1 lw 1
```

Then run this command:

```
gnuplot graph.gnuplot
```

And the graph will be generated as `graph.png`. You will probably need to adjust `yrange` (and maybe other variables) so give it a try with just a few values first.

Answer (score 0):

Conceivably reading the file into Python's `Pandas` `DataFrame` object is better than using just gnuplot:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv

The advantage is that you can slice, dice and display data further using `Pandas` facilities. `QtConsole` is very useful interactive shell for this kind of work.